# How to select clickable date when 2 date present on calendar selenium java?

Tags: java, list, selenium, automation, calendar

We are using a bootstrap calendar when I try to select 29th Feb then debugger try to select 29th Jan which is disable/inactive then I got the response as an element not clickable.

There are 2 xpath for same date, i want to click on active date xpath.

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[contains(@title,'Arrival Date')]")
public WebElement DepartureDateButton;;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[contains(text(),'February')]")
public WebElement selectmonth;; 

@FindBy(xpath="//span[contains(text(),'29')]")

public WebElement selectdate;;  

WaitforElementtobeVisible(selectmonth);
    WaitforElementtobeclickable(selectmonth);
    selectmonth.click();    
    WaitforElementtobeclickable(selectdate);
    selectdate.click();
```

[image]

Comment: You can try to make a counter and when there is 29 it should increment. If it equals to 1 then it should click so it will not click on the first one but on 20th of February.

Comment: tried this also but sometimes 1st data is clickable and sometimes 2nd data is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the XPath. Look at the calendar. Clearly, the dates outside of the chosen month, are greyed out. That means their class has to be different.

You did not post the HTML for that element, so I have to assume, but you should to adopt the solution to your own case

```
@FindBy(xpath="//span[contains(text(),'29') and contains(@class, 'grayed')]")
```

Comment: ***below html code for 29 which is disable***
 <span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}" class="text-muted">29</span></button>
  


***below html code for 29 which i want to click***
<span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}">29</span></button>

Comment: Those two code snippets are the same. Are you sure you've posted the right one? If yes, then maybe we have to look at the parent elements. You could post a bigger portion of the code, by editing the question.